# Why am I getting 403 Forbidden status codes for static files served via nginx / php-fpm?

Tags: php, nginx

I have a folder structure like this:

```
/usr/share/nginx/idevaffiliate/install/templates/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
```

I'm getting 403 responses when trying to access this and other static files via the webserver:

```
[30/Aug/2016:04:56:33 +0100] "GET /idevaffiliate/install/templates/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 403 46 "http://example.com/idevaffiliate/install/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
```

Here is my nginx location directive:

```
location ~ ^/idevaffiliate/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
 rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
 root /usr/share/nginx/;
 expires 30d;
}

location ^~ /idevaffiliate {
    root /usr/share/nginx/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size off;
    autoindex_localtime on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
}
```

Folder permissions for all files and subdirectories:

```
[root@BTCUKSW001 nginx]# ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 12 nginx nginx 4096 Feb  3  2014 idevaffiliate
```

Excerpt from /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:

```
[www]
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0666
user = nginx
group = nginx
```

I have no idea why I'm having "access denied" problems with this.  Can anyone tell me why and how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You show two location blocks in your question. The first one looks like a redirect loop, but will never be entered because the second location block overrides it using the `^~` modifier. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for location block processing.

The reason you are receiving a 403 response for static files, is because you are asking `php5-fpm` to serve them. The `fastcgi_pass` directive in your `location ^~ /idevaffiliate` block sends all requests to `php5-fpm`, when it only wants to see PHP scripts.

There are a number of patterns available, but a common solution is to use a nested location to serve just the PHP files:

```
location ^~ /idevaffiliate {
    root /usr/share/nginx;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    ...

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great.  My initial attempt wasn't doing what I thought it was at all.  Time to refresh my knowledge!